# How Can I remove multiple times Children from the following code

Tags: jquery

```
$(".differentView").children().children().children().children().hasClass("text-uppercase");
 false
$(".differentView").children().children().children().children().children().hasClass("text-uppercase");
 true
```

Comment: use `.find()` instead of multiple `.children()`

Comment: What's your question? Please add your markup.

Comment: You can use `find()` instead

Answer (score 0):

Use **[find()](http://api.jquery.com/find)** and length property to get the number of elements or for  their presence like

```
$(".differentView").find(".text-uppercase").length;
```

And for the specific child level use **[nth-child-selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)**

For egs,

```
$(".differentView :nth-child(5)").hasClass("text-uppercase");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .find() method with passing selector / element as an argument. FYR please see this link https://api.jquery.com/find/